# modify the values - pass by reference

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it bad practice to modify the values in the `calculateLineTotals()` which is passed by reference? If so, do I need to clone a line and then return it?

Example demo below:

```js
const data = {
  lines: [
    {
      Title: "Item One",
      Size: "Large",
      ProductId: "5535-43",
      Price: 10,
      TotalIncTax: 0,
      TotalExclTax: 0,
      Tax: 0,
      TaxPercent: 20,
      Qty: 2,
    }
  ]
};

function calculateData(data) {
  for(const line of data.lines) {
    calculateLineTotals(line);
  }

  return data;
}

function calculateLineTotals(line) {
  const qty = line.Qty
  const price = line.Price;
  const taxRate =  line.TaxPercent;

  const totalIncTax = price * qty;
  const totalExclTax = totalIncTax / ((taxRate + 100) / 100);
  const tax = (totalIncTax - totalExclTax);

  line.TotalIncTax = totalIncTax;
  line.TotalExclTax = totalExclTax;
  line.Tax = tax;

  return line;
}

console.log(calculateData(data));
```

Comment: it depends on if anything downstream will mind the changes. you are mutating the source, which can be good (cleanup/helpful) or bad (destructive/confusing).

Comment: @dandavis can you provide example answer how to avoid mutating the source?

Comment: make the first line of _calculateLineTotals_ `line = {...line};` for the simple one-level object code shown. If going deep, then you want to use`line=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(line))` instead for the top line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it bad practice to modify the values in the `calculateLineTotals()` which is passed by reference?

Not necessarily. It depends on your application use case. If you don't need the original data further downwards anyway, it's totally fine to mutate it. In your example, the properties that are written to seem *empty* (a value of `0`), it's probably fine to have a function that *fills in* the results. Nonetheless, it's a good practice to name and document the mutating functions accordingly. You might even drop the `return` value to make it clear to the caller that he won't get a new value.

> If so, do I need to clone a line and then return it?

Yes, although with modern ES6 syntax it's less of a "cloning" and more of just creating a completely new object.

```
function calculateLineTotals(line) {
  const {Qty: qty, Price: price, TaxPercent: taxRate} = line;

  const totalIncTax = price * qty;
  const totalExclTax = totalIncTax / ((taxRate + 100) / 100);
  const tax = (totalIncTax - totalExclTax);

  return {...line, TotalIncTax: totalIncTax, TotalExclTax: totalExclTax, Tax: tax};
}

function calculateData(data) {
  return {lines: data.lines.map(calculateLineTotals)};
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Do you have any idea how can I abstract each calculation individually such as `const totalExclTax = totalIncTax / ((taxRate + 100) / 100);` so it can be tested using jest? Secondly what design pattern I can follow? It will be a lot of mapping and and calculation in `calculateLineTotals()` Let say 30 fields.

Comment: Break them apart in smaller functions that do parts of the logic, or are related to each other more closely ([high cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science))). No, there's no reason to break it apart into individual statements. You still can test that with something like `expect(calculateLineTotals({…})).toHaveProperty("TotalExclTax", …)`.